# EXT JS - Overriding Framework's GridPanel's emptyText attribute

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

- **Updated Question**

I believe, we have the grid panel's emptyText defined to 'No Records to display' by default. Am i right? If so, Is there a getter and setter method pair that I can use to check the value and set it to a customized message?

An example of when I want to use a getter method:

- Customized gridpanel class with more user defined functions

  ```
     Ext.define('Everest.ux.grid.Panel', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
        alias: 'widget.extGridPanel',

        appId: '',

        more customized methods
        ....
  ```
- My Grid Component Class extending the above defined

  ```
  Ext.define('Everest.ux.grid.MyGrid', {

      extend: 'Everest.ux.grid.Panel',
      alias: 'widget.myGrid',

      screenId: '',
      moduleId: '',

      initComponent : function() {
         var me = this;
         me.firstTimeLoaded = false;
         me.callParent();
      },
      ....


          var customStore = new Ext.data.Store({                          
              fields: customStoreFields,
              groupField: groupByDefaultField,
              sorters: customSorters,
              sortOnLoad: !Ext.isEmpty(customSorters),
              proxy: {
                  type: Ext.isEmpty(me.proxyType) ? 'ajax' : me.proxyType,
                  url: customDefinedURL,
                  reader: {
                      type: 'json'
                  }
              }
          });

          **me.reconfigure(customStore, newCustomFields);**
  ```

me refers to my grid component. I have not defined emptyText attribute in any of my customized components but im still seeing that 'No Records to display' message while the grid is fetching data. I am thinking me.reconfigure is the place where im seeing the message even while the grid is fetching data.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. May be you are loading an empty store or something first? Show us more code

Comment: @hop - Thanks for your reply. That helped me narrow down to my problem. I updated my question. Please let me know if i need to provide any details. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when using local data the emptyText will not be displayed unless you set the deferEmptyText option to false.

Why can't you try with autoload:true in store (Let it be false, if require).

Please refer below link for emptyText definition.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-emptyText

Thanks.

Comment: I am not using local data. And yes, that was my first choice of referring to that Sencha's definition. 
However, I dont understand " (Let it be false, if require).". If I keep it that way, what else am I changing? I updated my question though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be the case. May be you are loading an empty store or something first?

> Yeah, I see we are loading an empty store initially and that explained
>   certain things. I believe, we have the grid's emptyText defined to 'No
>   Records to display' by default. Am i right?

No, you are wrong. You are setting the emptyText by this block in your code

```
viewConfig:{

        emptyText: 'No data to display',
        deferEmptyText: true

}
```

Also, what is worrying me is "deferEmptyText" defaults to true. Be more clear in what is the issue you are facing and what you exactly need.

Refer http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-deferEmptyText

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Both the scenarios are different. To make things more lucid, I deleted the original question. My grid component has a lot of other logic which basically loads the column names.